# How to get the value from my picker? Xamarin forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have trouble to get out the selected `string` from my picker.
This is my code:

XAML:

```xml
<Picker x:Name="thePicker" >
    <Picker.Items>
        <x:String>info1</x:String>
        <x:String>info2 </x:String>
    </Picker.Items>
</Picker>
```

CODE:

```cs
thePicker.SelectedIndex = 1; //here is the problem i suppose, any idea what i should type?
var ourPickedItem = thePicker.Items[thePicker.SelectedIndex];
```

Now I only get the value "info1" even if i select number 2. It has something to do with the `SelectedIndex` so it only picks the "1", but I am not sure how to write the code to make it work for the selected item.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should take a look at [this](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Xamarin.Forms.Picker/):

```cs
picker.SelectedIndexChanged += (sender, args) =>
{
    if (picker.SelectedIndex == -1)
    {
        boxView.Color = Color.Default;
    }
    else
    {
        string colorName = picker.Items[picker.SelectedIndex];
        boxView.Color = nameToColor[colorName];
    }
};
```

Otherwise in new Xamarin Forms Release 2.3.4 exists the

[Bindable Picker](https://blog.xamarin.com/new-bindable-picker-control-for-xamarin-forms/)

you can set an ItemSource

```
<Picker ItemsSource="{Binding Countries}" />
```

and Bind the SelectedIndex property

```
SelectedIndex="{Binding CountriesSelectedIndex}"
```

Answer (score 0):

XLabs is already providing it. Here is an example:

```
<ContentPage x:Class="XLabs.Samples.Pages.Controls.ExtendedPickerPage"
         xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:XLabs.Forms.Controls;assembly=XLabs.Forms"
         Title="Picker">
<ContentPage.Content>
    <StackLayout x:Name="myStackLayout">
        <Label Text="Xaml:" />
        <controls:ExtendedPicker x:Name="myPicker"
                                 DisplayProperty="FirstName"
                                 ItemsSource="{Binding MyDataList}"
                                 SelectedItem="{Binding TheChosenOne}" />
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage.Content>
```