# Getting selected value from Picker in Xamarin

Tags: xamarin.forms, picker

I am getting data from a web service and I am loading it in Picker. Now I want to call a new web service to get some data related to selected item. But I am not getting that selected item.

I am using below class model to get data from web service and loading it in Picker.

```
public class ModelGetEmployeeList
{
    public string ServiceStatus { get; set; }
    public List<EmployeeList> EmpList { get; set; }
}

public class EmployeeList
{
    public string uid { get; set; }
    public string fname { get; set; }
    public string lname { get; set; }
}
```

This is how I loaded data in `Picker`:

```
if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();
    var Items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject <ModelGetEmployeeList> (content);

    foreach(EmployeeList emp in Items.EmpList)
    {
        pickerEmployee.Items.Add(emp.uid.ToString()+"-"+emp.fname.ToString()+" "+emp.lname.ToString());
    }
}
```

Now I am implementing `SelectedIndexChanged` event like this:

```
public void PickerEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (pickerEmployee.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    {
        //Message
    } 
    else
    {
        var item = sender as EmployeeList;
        var selectedItem = item.uid;

        DisplayAlert (selectedItem.ToString (), "OK", "OK");
    }
}
```

But its giving me an error that above method has wrong signature.

Answer (score 5):

**You can take sellected value with this:**

```
 string selectedEmployee = string.Empty; 

 selectedEmployee = pickerEmployee.Items[pickerEmployee.SelectedIndex];
```

Answer (score 2):

According to the `Xamarin.Forms`  [Picker documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/event/Xamarin.Forms.Picker.SelectedIndexChanged/) `SelectedIndexChanged` event is expecting delegate which matches `EventHandler` delegate ([EventHandler documentation](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.EventHandler/))

So, you have to change signature of your method :

```
public void PickerEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: Ohh.. Thanks. This problem is solve but it has occurred new error. Object reference is not set at **var selectedItem = item.uid;**

Answer (score 1):

Your signature is wrong.

Also the following code is wrong:

```
var item = sender as EmployeeList;
var selectedItem = item.uid;
```

Please find the corrected version below :

```
    public void PickerEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (pickerEmployee.SelectedIndex == -1) 
        {
            //Message
        } 
        else
        {                
            var selectedItem = PickerEmployee[SelectedIndex]; 
            DisplayAlert (selectedItem, "OK", "OK");
        }
    }
```

The Xamarin Forms picker will get you only the string which was added to the list and not the object.

If you need the object either you can use the selectedIdex on your orginal lsit to get the object as :

```
var selectedEmp = Items.EmpList[SelectedIndex];
```

Or you can use a [Bindable Picker](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/30801/xamarin-forms-bindable-picker).

Comment: Thank you sir. I need to get uid from the selected text. I separated uid and employee name with "dash" so I can get uid without accessing object.

Answer (score 1):

```
public void PickerEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (pickerEmployee.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    {
        //Message
    } 
    else
    {                
        var selectedItem = (EmployeeList)PickerEmployee.SelectedItem; 
        DisplayAlert (selectedItem.fname, "OK", "OK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public void PickerEmployee_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (pickerEmployee.SelectedIndex == -1) 
    {
        //Message
    } 
    else
    {
        var item = sender as Picker;
        var selectedItem = item.SelectedItem as EmployeeList;
        var uid =selectedItem.uid;
        DisplayAlert (uid .ToString (), "OK", "OK");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The Items collection is a list of strings so you can get the currently selected value using SelectedIndex

```
 var selectedValue = picker.Items [picker.SelectedIndex];
```

If you are using binding then yes, the exposed property is the SelectedIndex.

For more info click [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34502290/how-to-get-the-value-from-my-picker-xamarin-forms)

Answer (score 0):

```
     //How to get value of picker in Xamarin forms 
 //We are getting Text and Value from API
 
 
 //xaml page
 
        <controls:BorderlessPicker
                                    x:Name="Pickdoctype" 
                                    ItemDisplayBinding="{Binding text}"
                                    SelectedIndexChanged="Pickdoctype_SelectedIndexChanged"
                                    HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand"                                                                     
                                    Title="Enter Document Type"
                                    FontSize="20" 
                                    TextColor="Gray">
        </controls:BorderlessPicker>
        
        
        
// xaml.cs page 

    private void Pickdoctype_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            DocumentTypeModel selectedItem = (DocumentTypeModel)Pickdoctype.SelectedItem;
            updatePickerValue = selectedItem.value;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }


  // class 


      public class DocumentTypeModel
{
    
    public string text { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```